# ivy.xml to pom.xml file

Tags: maven, ant, ivy

I am attempting to replace our internal Ivy repository with Artifactory and converting everything to Maven.  The current repository is hosted on one of our servers in subversion and I am trying to get away from this.  My biggest question has to do with the markdown of the **ivy.xml** and how it relates to **pom.xml**.  I used the ant task **makepom** to convert but it seems to exclude the configurations and the publications section in the **ivy.xml** file.  To be honest, I am new to ivy and maven and can't seem to find anything that explains this is maven terms.  The particular file in question looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="../../../../xsl/ivy-doc.xsl"?>
<ivy-module xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../xsd/ivy.xsd">

<info organisation="net.java.dev.jna" module="jna" revision="3.4.0" status="release" publication="20111210120000">
    <license name="GNU Lesser General Public License, version 2.1 or later" url="http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.html"/>
    <ivyauthor xmlns:ivyde="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/ns/" name="Ivy RoundUp Repository" url="https://github.com/archiecobbs/ivyroundup/blob/master/src/modules/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.4.0/"/>
    <repository xmlns:ivyde="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/ivyde/ns/" pattern="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/archiecobbs/ivyroundup/master/repo/modules/[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivy.xml" ivys="true" url="https://github.com/archiecobbs/ivyroundup" name="ivyroundup"/>
    <description homepage="https://github.com/java-native-access/jna">
</info>

<configurations>
    <conf name="core" description="JNA core library"/>
    <conf name="platform" description="JNA platform library"/>
    <conf name="default" extends="core,platform" description="JNA core + platform library"/>
</configurations>

<publications>
    <artifact name="jna" ext="pom" type="pom"/>
    <artifact conf="core" name="jna"/>
    <artifact conf="core" name="jna-source" type="source" ext="zip"/>
    <artifact conf="core" name="jna-javadoc" type="javadoc" ext="zip"/>
    <artifact conf="platform" name="platform"/>
    <artifact conf="platform" name="platform-source" type="source" ext="zip"/>
    <artifact conf="platform" name="platform-javadoc" type="javadoc" ext="zip"/>
</publications>
```

The pom file I have created looks like so

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
   Apache Maven 2 POM generated by Apache Ivy
   http://ant.apache.org/ivy/
   Apache Ivy version: 2.4.0 20141213170938
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <url>https://github.com/java-native-access/jna</url>
</project>
```

I've omitted some of the code connecting to our server.  Trying to publish with maven publishes an empty jar file, I want to just publish the existing 3rd party jar.  Any ways, if I could get some more clarification on migrating that **publications** block over to the pom file, that would be great.

Comment: Sorry but I really got to ask - why are you doing this? Why not simply continue using ivy?

Comment: That would indeed be the easier solution but the developers here want to start using maven.

Comment: Well in that case, if people want to start using something else, gradle is much better choice then maven IMHO.

Comment: yea, I converted our Ivy builds to gradle already, this is merely for our internal artifact repository

Comment: Oh, but in that case simply make an ivy repository in artifactory, gradle support this https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.IvyArtifactRepository.html

Comment: ok, I will make a push for that.  Right now our gradle build does pull from an internal ivy repository that's hosted in subversion, it should be easy enough to switch to artifactory I would think.

Comment: Yup it's quite easy. I also worked once in a company where binaries were stored in SVN also ... :\

Comment: out fo curiosity, would there even be any benefit to migrating to a maven repository?

Comment: Subjectively  - absolutely not. Objectively - I can't think of any.

Comment: Well that solves that.  Thank you

Comment: You are welcome